# How to center author name and affiliations?

Tags: titles, author, wlscirep

my current code is as below:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\title{\centering cccccc}
\author{xxxx}
\affil{vvvvv}
\affil{vvvvv}
```

and it is appearing as below

[image]

How do i make the author name and the affiliation details to appear in the middle below the title instead? thank you.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) please make this into a full minimal example, not just a sniplet (makes it a lot easier for others to test), (3) were is that class available, it does not seem to be a class distributed with LaTeX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the class definition file.  However, you can change the format.  The command that produces the titles is `\@maketitle`.  It contains the command `\raggedright` two times, once for the title and once for the author information.  Replacing each instance by `\centering` produces the required result.  This can be achieve by patching the command as follows

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt]{wlscirep}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\raggedright}{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{cccccc}
\author{xxxx}
\affil{vvvvv}
\affil{vvvvv}
\begin{abstract}
  x
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```